# swift - Function that fetches and appends Firebase values returns an empty string

Tags: arrays, swift, function, firebase

I'm trying to create a function that grabs the category children's keys of a given user UID in Firebase, appends them to an array and then finally joins them together into one long string. Everything works well until the observeSingleEvent function completes and the return value is empty. Here's my code:

```
let referenceDatabase = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

func fetchBuddyInfo(category: String, buddyId: String) -> String {

    var buddyInterestsArray = [String]()
    var buddyInterests = String()

    referenceDatabase.child("Users").child(buddyId).child(category).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (categorySnap) in

        for categoryItems in categorySnap.children.allObjects as! [FIRDataSnapshot] {

            buddyInterestsArray.append(categoryItems.key)
         }

         buddyInterests = buddyInterestsArray.joined(separator: ",")
    })
    return buddyInterests
}
```

I think it has something to do with the nested scope of the observeSingleEvent function since buddyInterests seems to lose its value after running the function, but I can't figure out how to pull the value out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problem

`observeSingleEvent(of:with:)` is an asynchronous operation, which means that it can return later after executing the function. That's why in your case you get always an empty String as return value

### Solution

So in your case you can create a completion handler like this:

```
func fetchBuddyInfo(category: String, buddyId: String, completion: @escaping (String) -> ()) {

  var buddyInterestsArray = [String]()
  var buddyInterests = String()

  referenceDatabase.child("Users").child(buddyId).child(category).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (categorySnap) in

    for categoryItems in categorySnap.children.allObjects as! [FIRDataSnapshot] {

      buddyInterestsArray.append(categoryItems.key)
    }

    buddyInterests = buddyInterestsArray.joined(separator: ",")

    completion(buddyInterests)
  })
}
```

And call your function like this:

```
fetchBuddyInfo(category: categoryString, buddyId: buddyId) { (buddyInfoString) in
  // do whatever you want with your buddyInfoString
}
```

Comment: Perfect, great that I could help you!